# How to compare cells from different rows within the same project in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine

I have a set of data with a column named `START` containing date values.

Is there a way to compare the `START` value of a row against all other `START` values inside the project?

I'd like to create a new column with a message like this `"Rows n° x,y,...,z contains greater START values".`

I've tried the following using `"cell.cross"` function to compare two projects (actually the same project) but it seems to be too resource and time consuming:

```
1. create a new column COMPARE with a fixed value
2. use "cell.cross" function against column COMPARE to import in every row all the START values of the project, collapsed in a new column named ALL_START_VALUES
3. compare START value against the array in ALL_START_VALUES and generate log
```

Too bad, my 200k rows project freezes during step n°2.

This is what i'd like to obtain:

> ROW | START      | LOG
>
> 0 | 2019-01-**01**T00:00:00Z | Rows n° 1,2 contain greater START values
>
> 1 | 2019-01-**02**T00:00:00Z | Rows n° 2 contain greater START values
>
> 2 | 2019-01-**03**T00:00:00Z |

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your step 2 involves creating a project containing 200,000 cells containing 200,000 elements each, i.e. 200,000^2 = 40 billion elements <- it is way too much to deal with for OpenRefine.

Then you would have to do 40 billion more calculations to compare each of your 200,000 dates with the other 200,000. At the rate of 1 millisecond per calculation, this would make 1111 hours of calculation, or 462 days...

You definitely need another tool than OpenRefine ([example in Python](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html)). And in any case, you will need to develop a technique to reduce the number of comparisons. The most common in this type of case is [blocking](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3191). It consists in comparing only values that are already close enough (for example only dates with the same year). But it is difficult to suggest a strategy without knowing your data.

Answer (score 0):

OpenRefine is a data cleaning power tool that can import and export tabular data from Databases, but it itself is not a Database.

If you want to inspect values on a column that contains Dates or Text or whatever, you can apply various Facet's using the column menu.  As Ettore says, you might run into trouble if the dataset you are working with is millions or billions of rows (that might take a lot of RAM allocated to OpenRefine).

Your use case might be closer to that of needing a Database that supports functions.  In the RDBMS world, I would suggest PostgreSQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenRefine doesn't easily support operations that work between multiple rows. You can use the 'Records' mode to achieve this to a degree, but you will have performance issues if you try to create a Record which contains 200k rows.

So I suspect that OpenRefine is not the best tool for you to solve this problem

In terms of how you actually approach the problem overall - it feels like this is a "sort" problem really - if you sort the rows based on the date in the START column then every row below that contains a greater than or equal start date. From there it would be reasonably easy to generate the statements you want in the LOG column - working down the START column you just need to find the first row that contains a a later date, and then you know all the rows under that also contain a later date. (I can see a way of doing this in OpenRefine but it's pretty complicated - I don't think it's the best solution)

Hope this is of some help